# Incorrect colors when reconstructing an image from arrays with pygame/pyglet

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet

I wrote up this program that would use numpy and Image(PIL) library to read an image as a bunch of matrices and use pyglet(and opengl) to reconstruct the image.

The code using pyglet is as follows:

```
import Image
import numpy
import window
import sys
import pyglet
import random
a=numpy.asarray(Image.open(sys.argv[1]))
h,w= a.shape[0],a.shape[1]
s=a[0]
print s.shape

#######################################
def display():
    x_a=0;y_a=h
    for page in a:
        for array in page: 
            j=array[2]
            k=array[1]
            l=array[0]
            pyglet.gl.glColor3f(l,j,k)
            pyglet.gl.glVertex2i(x_a,y_a)
            x_a+=1
        y_a-=1  
        x_a=0
######################################33
def on_draw(self):
    global w,h

    self.clear
    pyglet.gl.glClear(pyglet.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    pyglet.gl.glBegin(pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS)
    display()
    pyglet.gl.glEnd()
    pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save('screenshot.png')
window.win.on_draw=on_draw

#######################################

u=window.win(w,h)
pyglet.app.run()
```

The same code modified to use the pygame library (and which is devoid of any opengl usage)

```
import pygame
import numpy
import Image
import sys
from pygame import gfxdraw

color=(255,255,255)

a=numpy.asarray(Image.open(sys.argv[1]))
h,w=a.shape[0],a.shape[1]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))

def uu():
    y_a=0
    for page in a:
        x_a=0
        for array in page:
            co=(array[0],array[1],array[2])
            pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(screen,x_a,y_a,co)
            x_a+=1
        y_a+=1

uu()
done = False

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        pygame.display.flip()
```

The result from pyglet vs. pygame:

[image: pyglet vs pygame]

So my question is...why is there a problem? Is there a problem with the way I utilised opengl to draw the picture pixel by pixel or there something else that is for now beyond my comprehension?

Comment: You don't explain what isn't working. Are you expecting it to use the image as a normal texture in pyglet?

Comment: well,a very battered form of the image appears instead of a perfect one..I would have posted the original pic and the output from the above code..but since I am a newbie with no ranking or reputation ,I can't do so.

Comment: You can post images on imgur, and link it. Are you using pygame and PIL and pyglet? I didn't see an import but you're tagged as pygame so I was confused. -- I did searching for you but I can't find the specific post. There's a way to load pygame surfaces as opengl (pyglet) textures.

Comment: My apologies, hopefully the edit should make things more unambiguous.

Comment: how about trying it with a super small picture of RGBW values? 4px picture, that way you will see if its wrong for all color values globally.

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion...I have two code snippets that does exactly the same thing but with different libraries and main algorithm is the same. One snippet works and other doesn't.So my question is WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pygame.Color` expects integers in the range 0-255, while `pyglet.gl.glColor3f` expects floats in the range 0.0-1.0.  A conversion like this should fix your problem:

```
j=array[0] / 255.0
k=array[1] / 255.0
l=array[2] / 255.0
pyglet.gl.glColor3f(j,k,l)
```